# How to get images to show in Media when saved Via PHP

Tags: uploads

I saved a bunch pictures ( 2,000+ ) in a PHP script. I can see the list of files with adequate permissions for apache to view them in my /wp-content/2016/05 directory but They aren't showing up in my media folder.

Is there a plugin for this that can help me out? Has this happened to anyone previously? What did you do to fix it?

I google'd across the plugin *Add From Server* but I have no clue how it's supposed to help me with my problem and the Youtube video that the Plugin suggests, is rather pointless, seems like marketing for their company more than anything.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Add From Server plugin actually was my answer. I just didn't know how to use it when I ran across it at first.

When you click or hover on the WordPress Dashboard on the left over 'Media' you will see 'Add From Server' navigate through your directories and choose which file(s) you'd like to add.

Found that information from here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ftp-images-not-showing-up-in-media-library

Answer (score -1):

try inserting image url on wp_posts table. use url as guid and post_type : attachment.